# Advantage or disadvantages of SMD over Through hole design in high frequencies?

Tags: surface-mount, through-hole

I know this is an elementary question.

I know that SMD design has the advantage of smaller board size but I dont know which design works better in higher frequencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on your design but if I wanted use a design for high frequencies, I used through hole just for power/heating parts and used SMD for the rest because SMD design can reduce inductance and resistance of component parts .

Advantages of SMD:

1-Smaller components.

2- Much higher component density (components per unit area) and many more connections per component.

3-Lower initial cost and time of setting up for production.
Fewer holes need to be drilled.

4-Simpler and faster automated assembly.

5- Small errors in component placement are corrected automatically as the surface tension of molten solder pulls components into alignment with solder pads.

6-Components can be placed on both sides of the circuit board.

7-Lower resistance and inductance at the connection; consequently, fewer unwanted RF signal effects and better and more predictable high-frequency performance.

8-Better mechanical performance under shake and vibration conditions.

9-Many SMT parts cost less than equivalent through-hole parts.

10-Better EMC compatibility (lower radiated emissions) due to the smaller radiation loop area (because of the smaller package) and the smaller lead inductance.

Disadvantages of SMD:

1- Manual prototype assembly or component-level repair is more difficult

2-SMDs cannot be used directly with  breadboards

3-SMDs' solder connections may be damaged by potting compounds going through thermal cycling.

4- SMT is unsuitable for large, high-power, or high-voltage parts, for example in power circuitry.

5-SMT is unsuitable as the sole attachment method for components that are subject to frequent mechanical stress

Comment: Is advantage #5 really an advantage over through-hole? What is the initial placement tolerance for an 0402 SMT resistor vs a 0.1" 1/8W through-hole resistor? Is it an issue?

Comment: I agree with RedGrittyBrick, advantage #5 isn't really an advantage. In fact, it hides an unmentioned disadvantage: the fact that SMT components placed wrongly can result in shorts between individual pins.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I meant during "manual" placement, if the device is not properly put on the pads "before" soldering, the part automatically goes to correct position with molten solder.You are right I should explained it better

Comment: Why #4 is a disadvantage for large high power? I have seen several design with 250 V be decoupled with SMT capacitor ceramic.

Comment: @user83494 SMD components are typically limited to shorter components than through-hole, which automatically means lower voltage withstanding. Also, even for the same cross-section (square area), an SMD resistor will not only has smaller surface area (thin rectangle vs. circle area), but one side of it is against the board, meaning it doesn't come into a direct contact with air to exchange the heat with it, so a significantly smaller area actually dissipates the heat into the surrounding air.