# chip resistor/capacitor size vs performance for analog circuits

Tags: capacitor, pcb, resistors, analog, packages

I am designing one four layer ADS1298 (TI) based analog PCB. Signal frequency is about 1.5Hz to 3.79kHz. It is a four layer board with most of the components and traces on top layer and the ground plane/power plane on the second and third layer.

Since the board needs to be small, i am thinking about using small package resistors and capacitors, such as 0402. I know that for resistors, the smaller size leads to lower power. However, it is not a big issue in my case.

My question is whether there are some other things I need to pay attention to for using smaller package passive components.

Edit 2: found this link talking about capacitor selection. Still looking for the resistor related articles.....

[What parameters to look at when comparing capacitors of same value but different package size](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125815/what-parameters-to-look-at-when-comparing-capacitors-of-same-value-but-different?rq=1)

Thanks

Comment: I saw the other question you posed. The best thing in this case might be to get the reference design package, study it, and implement the parts you want. 

http://www.ti.com/tool/ads1298ecgfe-pdk

Comment: Take the part of interest and look at it's specs! That's the only way to find out.

Comment: I got this package. The questions I asked were practical design questions. I am not worrying about the function of the chip anymore.

Comment: Duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84946/advantage-or-disadvantages-of-smd-over-through-hole-design-in-high-frequencies although what you're doing is not high frequency, the same advantages are obtained.

Comment: For capacitors, there are more lies than capacitance as you go up in values. Your "1 uF, 16 V" is far less than 1 uF @ 16 V, although it is 1 uF at 0 V and can withstand 16 V. When you go down in size, this "phenomon" becomes worse. For small values, < ~47 nF, no problem with small packages.

Comment: Thanks winny. In the design, I am using small values such as hundreds pf.

Comment: Hi Captainj2001, My question is not about choosing between through holes and SMDs. My question is about the smd sizes vs performance.

Comment: One very general rule of thumb: As the size gets smaller, parasitic inductance decreases (but 0402 is really tiny). Inductance may not matter in your application.